# Checking if file contains string

Tags: php, redirect

I've tried loads of different methods and none of them seem to work, all I want to do is make the page echo something if the number one appears on the page, the contents of the page will always be either "0" or "1", if it's "1" all I need it to do is echo something like "value set to one"

```
 <?php 
variablee = fopen('textfile.txt', "rb");
echo stream_get_contents($variablee);  

if (stristr($variablee,'1'))
{
echo "value at one"
}
?>
```

This is the one I thought was most likely to work, mainly because it's the most simple out of all the solutions I found, and me not being the best at php, I find this easy to understand. the problem is when I go to the page where the php code is, nothing happens, the page remains blank.

Comment: blank => http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php /// add an `else { echo "ELSE"; }`, what happens? Parse error or "ELSE" echoes?

Comment: Parse error; given what you posted is missing closure on the last echo.

Answer (score 0):

The content of the file is obtained by the `stream_get_contents` function, $variable just contains a reference to the file, not it's content. Try this:

```
<?php 
$variable = fopen('textfile.txt', "rb");
$content = stream_get_contents($variable);
echo $content;

if (stristr($content,'1'))
{
    echo "value at one"
}
```